# Unable to build test project(tess4j) tesseract application

Tags: java, netbeans, tesseract, tess4j

I have configured tess4j test application as http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/.
But when I run the project, it gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain updateLastError method for class com.sun.jna.Native
at com.sun.jna.Native.initIDs(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:148)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at tstest.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Java Result: 1
```

I am unable to find any comments related to tesseract, If anyone have done in this project please help.

This is the example code I am using:

```
import java.io.*;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File imageFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\images\\1.png");
    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance(); //

    try {

        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);

    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Could the problem be solved? What was the source of the problem?

Comment: Looks like you have an old `jna.jar` somewhere in your class path.

Answer (score 0):

Which JNA version are you using? Have you build it first? As explained on your linked page.

Based on the log in repository `https://github.com/twall/jna.git` the method `updateLastError(int e)` was removed in March 2013 (SHA1: [d8e8889d](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/commit/d8e8889d92b5c2ffa245e6bd20c3278bb408a72f#diff-02cbcdcad9148f413bae67326f2b08c2L843)).

To find out the JNA version execute

```
java -jar jna.jar 

Java Native Access (JNA) API Version 4
Version: 4.2.1 (b0)
Native: 4.0.1 (1a6047467b59e8748f975e03016ce3d9)
Prefix: linux-x86-64
```

**edit** A complete simple example was posted here: [issue-with-the-libtesseract303-dll-in-netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547211/issue-with-the-libtesseract303-dll-in-netbeans)

Comment: How can I see version of jna.jar

Comment: @user5954693 Have a look in my updated answer. You should also check the example code you are using (could you post it?). Seems your example code rely on a method which was removed in 2013. The current version of Tess4J ([Tess4J-3.0-src.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/files/latest/download)) does not contain this function call.

Comment: I tried to run as you said..`java -jar jna.jar`. It gives following error      `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain updateLastError method for class com.sun.jna.Native
        at com.sun.jna.Native.initIDs(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:148)
`

Comment: yes you are right. I am using [Tess4J-3.0-src.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/files/latest/download) .. In this case how can I configure mytest project.

Comment: @user5954693 Have a look to the link I added. It point to a complete working example.

Comment: I have used almost similar test application.as you can see the code I provided in my question.

Comment: @user5954693 Why not updating your JNA? I mean, it really states that this is the source of your problem. You can get a recent version from https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/releases. If it still does not work for you. Post more information about your setup. Where your `jna.jar` is comming from etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106340/discussion-between-user5954693-and-suboptimal).